# Wondering how to let the user add to a linked list?

Tags: c#, linked-list, nodes

I have created three classes `LinkedList.cs` `Node.cs` `Program.cs` and now I'm wondering how I use them to there full potentional. I want the user to be able to create a new dinosaur that is stored in the linked list but I'm not sure how to go about doing this, I know I need to use a linked list cause I need them to be able to add at any point and remove from any point of the list.

I'm sure that the `LinkedList.cs` has the functionality to do all of this but I'm not sure how I use it to do what I'm trying to do which is to allow the user to create a new dinosaur, add it to any position in the list and remove a dinosaur from any position in the list.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.ExceptionServices;
using System.Text;

namespace JurrasicFinal
{
    public class LinkedList
    {

        private Node head;
        private int count;

        public LinkedList()
        {
            this.head = null;
            this.count = 0;
        }

        public bool Empty
        {
            get { return this.count == 0; }
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get { return this.count; }
        }

        public object this[int index]
        {
            get { return this.Get(index); }
        }

        public object Add(int index, object o)
        {
            if (index < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Index: " + index);

            if (index > count)
                index = count;

            Node current = this.head;

            if (this.Empty || index == 0)
            {
                this.head = new Node(o, this.head);
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++)
                {
                    current = current.Next;
                    current.Next = new Node(o, current.Next);
                }
            }
            count++;
            return o;
        }

        public object Add(object o)
        {
            return this.Add(count, o);
        }

        public object Remove(int index)
        {
            if (index < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Index: " + index);

            if (this.Empty)
                return null;

            if (index >= this.count)
                index = count - 1;

            Node current = this.head;
            object result = null;

            if (index == 0)
            {
                result = current.Data;
                this.head = current.Next;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; index < index - 1; i++) ;
                current = current.Next;

                result = current.Next.Data;
                current.Next = current.Next.Next;
            }

            count--;

            return result;

        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            this.head = null;
            this.count = 0;
        }

        public int IndexOf(object o)
        {
            Node current = this.head;

            for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++)
            {
                if (current.Data.Equals(o))
                    return i;

                current = current.Next;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        public bool Contains(object o)
        {
            return this.IndexOf(o) >= 0;
        }

        public object Get(int index)
        {
            if (index < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Index: " + index);

            if (this.Empty)
                return null;

            if (index >= this.count)
                index = this.count - 1;

            Node current = this.head;

            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
                current = current.Next;

            return current.Data;
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace JurrasicFinal
{
    public class Node
    {
        private object data;
        private Node next;

        public Node(object data, Node next)
        {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
        }

        public object Data
        {
            get { return this.data; }
            set { this.data = value; }
        }

        public Node Next
        {
            get { return this.next; }
            set { this.next = value; }
        }

    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace JurrasicFinal
{
    class Program
    {

        class Dinosaur
        {
            public string Name;
            public string Classification;
            public char Sex;
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LinkedList<Dinosaur> DinoList = new LinkedList<Dinosaur>();

            Dinosaur Dino1 = new Dinosaur();
            Dino1.Name = "Tyrannosaurus Rex";
            Dino1.Classification = "Carnivorous";
            Dino1.Sex = 'M';

            Dinosaur Dino2 = new Dinosaur();
            Dino2.Name = "Velociraptor";
            Dino2.Classification = "Carnivorous";
            Dino2.Sex = 'F';

            Dinosaur Dino3 = new Dinosaur();
            Dino3.Name = "Procompsognathus";
            Dino3.Classification = "Carnivorous";
            Dino3.Sex = 'M';


            void printList()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Current Queue: ");
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                foreach (Dinosaur d in DinoList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + d.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine("Classification: " + d.Classification);
                    Console.WriteLine("Sex " + d.Sex);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n");
                }
            }
            DinoList.AddLast(Dino1);
            DinoList.AddLast(Dino2);
            DinoList.AddLast(Dino3);
            printList();
            Console.WriteLine(DinoList.Count);


            FileStream fileStream = File.OpenWrite("E:/University Work/Dinosaur.txt");
            BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fileStream);
            foreach (Dinosaur d in DinoList)
            {
                writer.Write(d.Name);
                writer.Write(d.Classification);
                writer.Write(d.Sex);
            }
            writer.Close();


            Console.WriteLine("Reading Back From File");
            FileStream file = File.OpenRead("E:/University Work/Dinosaur.txt");
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(file);
            for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Dinosaur d = new Dinosaur();
                d.Name = reader.ReadString();
                d.Classification = reader.ReadString();
                d.Sex = reader.ReadChar();
                DinoList.AddLast(d);
            }
            reader.Close();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: [How to insert in Linked List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62608756/insertion-at-nth-place-in-linked-list-showing-segmentation-error/62609391#62609391)   May be this could help you

Answer (score 0):

Your LinkedList is not generic but you are using it generically in Program class. It is little confusing to me.

your LinkedList is not even list. Try implement at least IEnumerable or better IList interface to achieve more user friendly structure.

And think if you really need to use linked list. Course to add an item into list you need to copy O(n) pointers (when you iterating list) It is a lot similar to copying standard List when you are using its predefined functions.
These functions are implemented as unsafe, so it's much faster.

It looks like reinventing the wheel here to me.